# Superagent: PUT-ing multipart form data

Tags: multipartform-data, superagent

Is it possible to do a PUT request with multipart form data?

With Superagent I would expect the following to work, but it doesn't.

```
var request = Request
  .put("http://localhost:8080/upload_file")
  .field("name", file.name)
  .field("size", file.size)
  .attach("file", file.file, file.file.name)
  .accept("application/json")
```

If I do a post, it works. The difference is the Content-Type. With the successful post request the Content-Type is `multipart/form-data; boundary=------WebKitFormBoundaryXg34NkBFcYWq60mH`.

If I were to set this manually how would I know what the boundary should be? It seems to be automatically generated by Superagent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably do a POST, per Tum's comment.

> If I were to set this manually how would I know what the boundary should be? It seems to be automatically generated by Superagent.

You should let Superagent manage that by itself - don't try to set the type yourself, leave off the type call and it will include the correct boundary identifier when it sets it as multi-part itself.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to do a PUT request with content-type multipart/form-data due to an underlying limitation in PHP as discussed here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55815

You might want to take a look at a 'hack' that was done for Symfony in Chekote/symfony: https://github.com/Chekote/symfony/commit/dc1279b2e4c0e9cbcb5b7d578891c31dd878b43b

Comment: superagent is a node library, not a PHP one